# How can you rename a Meteor package?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have published a couple of Meteor packages [on Atmosphere](http://atmospherejs.com) and have poorly named one of them. I would like to rename a package, but can't figure out how to do it easily.

Comment: Just FYI, atmosphere tag is for an async framework in Java not a catalog for Meteor packages.

Comment: Thanks @DonghwanKim. I've edited the tags accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/percolatestudio/atmosphere/issues/297#issuecomment-64942581) is a huge discussion about why not to rename packages, just imagine if someone already has your package in dependencies?

Anyways I see only one way:

1. Remove all code in old package
2. Add your new package as a dependency to old one
3. [Imply](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/pack_api_imply) new package in old